# need help saving to a text file in python

Tags: python

(Visual studio 2015)

I need help in adding file to python when the user inputs thier data

def print_board(board):

```
print "The board look like this: \n"

for i in range(3):
    print " ",
    for j in range(3):
        if board[i*3+j] == 1:
            print 'X',
        elif board[i*3+j] == 0:
            print 'O',  
        elif board[i*3+j] != -1:
            print board[i*3+j]-1,
        else:
            print ' ',

        if j != 2:
            print " | ",
    print

    if i != 2:
        print "-----------------"
    else: 
        print
```

def print_instruction():
    print "Please use the following cell numbers to make your move"
    print_board([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

def get_input(turn):

```
valid = False
while not valid:
    try:
        user = raw_input("Where would you like to place " + turn + " (1-9)? ")
        user = int(user)
        if user >= 1 and user <= 9:
            return user-1
        else:
            print "That is not a valid move! Please try again.\n"
            print_instruction()
    except Exception as e:
        print user + " is not a valid move! Please try again.\n"
```

def check_win(board):
    win_cond = ((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9),(1,5,9),(3,5,7))
    for each in win_cond:
        try:
            if board[each[0]-1] == board[each[1]-1] and board[each[1]-1] == board[each[2]-1]:
                return board[each[0]-1]
        except:
            pass
    return -1

def quit_game(board,msg):
    print_board(board)
    print msg
    quit()

def main():

```
# setup game
# alternate turns
# check if win or end
# quit and show the board

print_instruction()

board = []
for i in range(9):
    board.append(-1)

win = False
move = 0
while not win:

    # print board
    print_board(board)
    print "Turn number " + str(move+1)
    if move % 2 == 0:
        turn = 'X'
    else:
        turn = 'O'

    # get user input
    user = get_input(turn)
    while board[user] != -1:
        print "Invalid move! Cell already taken. Please try again.\n"
        user = get_input(turn)
    board[user] = 1 if turn == 'X' else 0

    # advance move and check for end game
    move += 1
    if move > 4:
        winner = check_win(board)
        if winner != -1:
            out = "The winner is " 
            out += "X" if winner == 1 else "O" 
            out += " :)"
            quit_game(board,out)
        elif move == 9:
            quit_game(board,"No winner :(")
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is a Q&A site, which requires a question from you

Comment: It looks like you are trying to open a string type instead of a DBConnection type at the end of your code.  Try change your strConnectionString.Open() and .Close() to cnnOLEDB.Open() and .Close().

Comment: That is still not a specific programming question and this is not a tutorial site.  PLEASE read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Your access database is `mathsquiz.accdb` (not mdb).

replace the provider:

```
 Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0
```

With  Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 provider:

```
 Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12
```

install driver [Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-eg/download/details.aspx?id=23734)